# Integration of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was watching a lesson in youtube on the wave equation and couldn't figure out how the person completed one of the steps where he integrated a second derivative.[image]

Comment: Not sure why he would integrate, from [*undetermined coefficients*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx), we could just write $m^2 - \omega^2 = 0 \implies m = \pm \omega$. Thus we have the two solutions, $w(t) =  e^{\pm \omega t}$. Same approach for the second.

Comment: better is we will see the whole document

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner dont know if this will help but this is the link  and it was minute 14 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJLympg3XMM

Comment: @Variable can you please expand how you got w(t) to be an exponential. I don't mind if you use your method i just want to understand how you integrated it to become an exponential. That is what im not getting.

Comment: @J.Doe: Does the link I provided give enough details?

Comment: @Variable yh, i just checked the link. I think i understand what it says. Thanks